# Running plexmediaserver on an OrangePi + Ubuntu 16.04. It works but the plexmediaserver service disables the router's wifi on boot. What is happening?

Tags: 16.04, networking, raspberrypi, arm

Setup:

Router

- ASUS RT-AC68U

Orange Pi PC Plus

- Running Ubuntu 16.04
- Installed/running plexmediaserver-installer
- Connected via ethernet directly to router

Desktop PC

- Windows
- Connected via ethernet directly to router

Laptop

- Windows
- Connected via Wifi to router

Phone

- Android
- Wifi

Chromecast

- Wifi

---

What's happening:

Shortly after the boot of the Pi, all devices connected to the router's wifi disconnect and are unable to reconnect, while all wired devices are fine.

The wifi SSID is still visible as a network on the wireless list, however no device can connect to it and all devices that were previously connected to it lose local and internet connectivity - eventually disconnecting.

(wifi devices: laptop, phone, chromecast).

I am using the desktop to ssh into the Pi.

Once the wifi drops, I ssh into the Pi via the desktop and turn off plex via:

```
sudo systemctl stop plexmediaserver
```

The devices reconnect to the wifi and act normal.

---

What I have tried:

- Disabling ipv6 (no effect)
- Using a live Ubuntu distribution on the laptop to see if I can connect (no effect)
- Restarting service after boot

Restarting the service after boot (via ssh from desktop) <s>seems to allow running the Plex server without wifi issues</s> has the laptop connected to the wifi but not the other devices:

```
sudo systemctl restart plexmediaserver
```

So I have added the above line to my `/etc/rc.local` so `plexmediaserver` restarts after login.

This isn't an ideal solution because I'm not sure what the router's Wifi has to do with `plexmediaserver` and why are wired connections unaffected? Feels like a brittle solution to a problem I don't understand.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this router is particularly sensitive to DLNA and that might be what's causing issues. I turned off Plex's DLNA feature and it seems everything is okay.

https://forums.plex.tv/discussion/104297/plex-taking-down-my-router/p2